# CFWheels "Hello Database" in true MVC format

Tags: model-view-controller, coldfusion, model, cfwheels

The "Hello Database" example at cfwheels.org includes only a controller and views. What would the app look like if it included a model? Total beginner here, and I want to know when and how to use a model.

http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-3/chapter/beginner-tutorial-hello-database

To make sure this is a programming question, what would the model code look like in the Hello World app? I'm guessing just a line or two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the example app follows all conventions and it is very simple application so there is no need to use model. 
But if you want to use model for that then it would go like this:
In model folder,
create a CFC file with name **User.cfc** and add following code in it

```
<cfcomponent extends="Model">
    <cffunction name="init">

    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

You can see there is nothing in the init function as there is no need to do anything as of now. But in case you want something you can add

```
<cfset table(name="users")>
```

in the init function.

Comment: If it's an appropriate question here, in general, what kinds of things go in the model? I would think stuff like naming queries. Would it be named queries or other database functions?

Comment: No naming quries will not go in the model. In model you can define your database relation, validation other properties related to the database table.for more info you can refer wheels association chapter and here are the fucntion list you can use in model http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-3/function/category/model-initialization

Comment: @abalter, Model is very broad concept to explain it here. But as for as what goes inside Model CFC's, Keshav has summed it up pretty nicely. But remember there are more things related to model. Check out the following links along with a link provided by Keshav:
http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-3/function/category/model-object
http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-3/function/category/model-class
http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-3/chapter/associations